# Why does OSX document atoi/atof as not being threadsafe?

Tags: c, macos

I understand that strtol and strtof are preferred to atoi/atof, since the former detect errors, and also strtol is much more flexible than atoi when it comes to non-base-10.

But I'm still curious about something:  'man atoi' (or atof) on OS X (though not on Linux!) mentions that atoi/atof are not threadsafe.  I frankly have a hard time imagining a possible implementation of atoi or atof that would not be threadsafe.  Does anybody know why the man page says this?  Are these functions actually unsafe on OS X or any other platform?  And if they are, why on earth wouldn't the library just define atoi in terms of strtol, and therefore be safe?

Comment: most atoi implementations are just strtol wrappers it seems.

Comment: I've changed the title of this question so that it's at least a valid question.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/atof.3.html

Comment: Well, it is possible to *imagine* a non-thread-safe implementation: atof could access the current locale, and this might be unsafe if another thread changed the locale settings. However, as R.. pointed out, nowadays POSIX seems to require that atof is thread-safe.

Comment: @Jukka: Indeed, calling any function that depends on locale while one thread is using `setlocale` results in undefined behavior, but this is considered separate (by POSIX) from those functions being thread-safe or not. Basically you cannot use `setlocale` except before creating any threads or under *extreme* synchronization. This is why `uselocale` etc. were introduced in POSIX 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at the manual page on MacOS X 10.6.6, it documents two functions, `atof()` and `atof_l()`, and I suspect that gives a hint as to why the function is deemed not thread-safe:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> double atof(const char *str);
>
> #include <xlocale.h>
> double atof_l(const char *str, locale_t loc);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `atof()` function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by str to double representation.
>
> It is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>       strtod(str, (char **)NULL);
> ```
>
> The decimal point character is defined in the program's locale (category LC_NUMERIC).
>
> While the `atof()` function uses the current locale, the `atof_l()` function may be passed a locale directly. See xlocale(3) for more information.
>
> **IMPLEMENTATION NOTES**
>
> The `atof()` function is not thread-safe and also not async-cancel-safe.
>
> The `atof()` function has been deprecated by `strtod()` and should not be used in new code.
>
> **ERRORS**
>
> The function `atof()` need not affect the value of `errno` on an error.

My suspicion is that if the current locale is changed by another thread while the `atof()` function is executing, the result is not guaranteed.  Otherwise, there seems to be no reason for the warning.

---

I've poked around for a definitive location of the Darwin C library source code, but have not found one.  If you go to the FreeBSD source code for [`atoi()`](http://svn.freebsd.org/viewvc/base/stable/8/lib/libc/stdlib/atoi.c?revision=196045&view=markup), it is clear that the function implementation is trivial:

```
int
atoi(str)
    const char *str;
{
    return (int)strtol(str, (char **)NULL, 10);
}
```

(Yes, not even using a prototyped definition!)

The man page for `strtol()` does not have the weasel wording about thread safety or async-cancel safety.  However, a quick look at the source code for [`strtol()`](http://svn.freebsd.org/viewvc/base/stable/8/lib/libc/stdlib/strtol.c?revision=196045&view=markup) shows that it uses `isspace()`, which is affected by locale:

ISO/IEC 9899:1999, Section 7.11.1.1 The setlocale function

> <sup>187</sup> The only functions in 7.4 whose behavior is not affected by the current locale are isdigit and isxdigit.

(Where §7.4 is for `<ctype.h>`.)

Now, while I'm not sure that this code is identical to what's in Darwin (MacOS X), it is likely to be similar.  I think that there could be room for errata in the man pages - it is not so clear whether the page that needs correction is the one for `atoi()` or the one for `strtol()`.

Comment: The `setlocale` function is not thread-safe and may not be called if any other thread could be in a function whose behavior depends on the locale. However, such functions are not deemed non-thread-safe. The comment about async-cancel-safety also seems rather odd, since POSIX is quite explicit that no functions except `pthread_setcanceltype`, `pthread_setcancelstate`, and `pthread_cancel` are async-cancel-safe.

Comment: This makes lots of sense.  It's too bad the docs aren't more specific that it's safe as long as your app isn't changing the locale (mine certainly isn't).  I'm no locale expert, but I'm not sure I understand how the locale would be used in atoi (atof, I understand -- decimal point).

Comment: @Larry: `atoi()` might be looking at the thousands separator and perhaps the grouping, I suppose...However, see my update to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research I think it's just legacy from the old days when `errno` was a global variable.  If you check FreeBSD `errno.h` [history](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/sys/sys/errno.h) starting from the [first revision](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/sys/sys/errno.h?rev=1.1.1.1;content-type=text%2Fplain), you'd see that it was originally defined as

```
extern int errno;           /* global error number */
```

and now it's a function.  I cannot think of any other reason really.

Though `atoi` always has been a wrapper around [`strtol`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/stdlib/strtol.c) which also sets `errno` and should then have the same thread safety.  It must be just a documentation issue.

Comment: On modern Linux systems, errno is thread-local, i.e. each thread has its own copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-583/stdlib/atoi-fbsd.c) of `atoi()` in Apple's libc (`atof()` is similar):

```
int
atoi(str)
    const char *str;
{
    return (int)strtol_l(str, (char **)NULL, 10, __current_locale());
}
```

And `strtol()`:

```
long
strtol(const char * __restrict nptr, char ** __restrict endptr, int base)
{
    return strtol_l(nptr, endptr, base, __current_locale());
}
```

Since man strtol makes no mention of a thread-safety problem with `strtol()`, you might draw one or more of several conclusions:

- the docs are wrong about `atoi()` being thread-unsafe,
- they're neglecting to mention that `strtol()` is also thread unsafe,
- they're being conservative by documenting that `atoi()` makes no promise of thread safety, even if the current implementation happens to be thread safe,
- they're out of date (a special case of being wrong, I suppose)

`__current_locale()` returns a pointer to a structure describing the thread's locale (unsurprisingly). However, if a thread-specific locale hasn't been set, `__current_locale()` returns a pointer to a global locale structure.  I supposed dealing with the global could be thread-unsafe, but then that issue would apply to `strtol()` as well.

Comment: That's the FreeBSD version.  Is there good reason to believe that it's identical on Mac OS X?

Comment: The clips came from a repository on http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-583

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a couple of years after the question was asked, and first answered.  On my Mac OS X 10.8.3 (circa March 2013), `man atoi` (or `man atof`) reads:

```
IMPLEMENTATION NOTES
  The atof() and atof_l() functions are thread-safe and async-cancel-safe.

  The atof() and atof_l() functions have been deprecated by strtod() and
  strtod_l() and should not be used in new code.
```

So the final word is probably that there was never a thread-safety issue here, only errors in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

One guess is that these function do not set errno in a thread safe way, but that mean something strange is going on with errno on macos and thread. Normally errno is a thread local variable.

Comment: You'd have to go out of your way to write a version that does not set `errno` in a thread-safe way, since simply `errno = foo;` is a perfectly safe way to set it.

Comment: Assigment of anything other than a bool isn't necessarily thread safe in c (or c++) without compiler specific extentions

Answer (score -3):

The premise of this question (in its original form, before I edited the title) is wrong. They are thread-safe. POSIX specifies that all functions are thread-safe unless otherwise documented (by POSIX), and the documentation does not say anything about these functions not being thread-safe. OSX purports to conform to POSIX, so they are thread-safe on OSX or else this is a bug and major conformance issue. I'm going to assume it's just a bug in the man pages...

Comment: So your answer is 'man atoi' is wrong on OSX?  That doesn't make the premise of this question wrong.

Comment: Yes. It wouldn't be the first time a vendor man page is wrong, or the last. I still don't know why they insist on writing their own man pages rather than just including the POSIX ones...

Comment: Oh, and I'm the one who changed the title of the question. The original question was "Why are atoi/atof not threadsafe?"

Comment: I'm happy to accept "the man page is wrong", but as far as I know, you are only speculating, which makes me nervous about the necessity (or lack thereof) of excising atoi calls from my multithreaded software.  Does anybody have firm evidence one way or the other?

Comment: -1, OSX does not conform to the POSIX standard, bugs exists and implementation of several tools differ from the standard.

Comment: @Anders: Mac OS X 10.5 and 10.6 are SUSv3 certified, which implies POSIX compliance.

Comment: @dreamlax, Well, if they are actually certified, then whoever issued it should be fired. http://www.weirdnet.nl/apple/rename.html

Comment: How could they copy BSD and then break it?

Comment: @R.. They could break it as a part of the process of banging it into submission to make it work with existing stuff - i.e. backwards compatibility etc. For instance, older versions of MacOS used (although it was generally never shown to the user) a different file path separator.