# integer extraction from string

Tags: c, string, integer, extract

I have an input argument string `const char* s`
I know that it starts the sequence of chars which are  integers representation ,this sequence could be of any length ,including 0.
After the integer sequence follows sequence of chars which are not integer representation.
for example `"23meeting","1h"`.
Is there some (builtin) C function which can extract the integer?
For example for "23meeting" such operation could be performed :

```
int x = needed_function("23meeting"); //results x = 23
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

atoi() should work fine for this.  It should stop at the first non-numeric character.

```
int x = atoi("23meeting")
```

EDIT: A comment implies that atoi() is not thread safe or is deprecated from the language.  There is some discussion of the thread safety of this function here:

[Why does OSX document atoi/atof as not being threadsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631310/why-does-osx-document-atoi-atof-as-not-being-threadsafe)

Can someone provide a reference to atoi not being thread safe?

And as far as I can tell atoi() is in C99 which is the latest standard (7.20.1.2).

Comment: Stop recommending `atoi` in 2011. It is deprecated and thread-unsafe on many platforms.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev at least in BSDs and Darwin, atoi just calls strtol. So there is no problem. Not sure about other systems though.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev can you provide a reference to atoi() being deprecated from C? Lots of things are not thread safe.  It's always buyer beware.  Also please provide reference to atoi() being not thread safe.

Comment: @Blagovest: deprecated? Can't find any reference to deprecation of `atoi` in either the [current C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) or the [upcoming one](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf).

Comment: @Guy: http://www.lemoda.net/tools/man/3/atoi; In fact, the thing that sucks most about `atoi` is that you have no way to do adequate error-handling after the call since it may return `0` either as a failure or as a valid value.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev It may suck (it's simple minded) but it does exactly what the question was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the string and can give the condition to get numbers

```
num=0;
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++) {
if(str[i]>=48 && str[i]<=57)
 num=num*10+(str[i]-48);
  printf("\n%d",num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `sscanf`:

```
char *str = "23meeting";
unsigned x;
sscanf(str, "%u", &x);
printf("%u\n", x);
```

For additional error-checking, though, you'll have to do some additional manual checks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `atoi()` or the complete `strtol()`:

```
int x = atoi("23meeting");
int x = (int)strtol("23meeting", (char **)NULL, 10);
```

Check the man pages on your system (section 3 in Unix).

Comment: +1 for `strtol` ... But what's with all the casts? They aren't needed in C and look like clutter to me.

Comment: Thanks @pmg . Actually it's just for being politically correct, or in other words, to be compliant with the [manual](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=atoi&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) and [implementation](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdlib/atoi.c?revision=165903&view=markup).

Answer (score 0):

[`atoi()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/atoi.html) should do what you want to, although a more robust implementation would use [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strtol.html).