# extract a string number in string of characters and numbers in C programming

Tags: c, string

is there any function can extract the number in string return the string of number?

example I have  the string :`assdf4fdsdf65fsafda5` want to output is string of number: `4 65 5`
and the input string unknow the length is.

I know there is the way that can extract is :

```
char *str = "ab234cid*(s349*(20kd", *p = str;
while (*p) { // While there are more characters to process
    if (isdigit(*p)) { // Upon finding a digit,
        long val = strtol(p, &p, 10); // Read a number,
        printf("%ld\n", val); // and print it.
    } else { // Otherwise, move on to the next character.
        p++;
    }
}
```

is there any function like `char extract(char input,char output){ ... return output;}` thank you

Comment: You want one number `4665` or 3 numbers `4 65 5`

Comment: I need the format is string of 3 numbers 4 65 5. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any function available but it would be reasonably easy to implement. The code below assumes that `output` has at least `strlen(input) + 2` bytes allocated. I'll leave it to you to remove the trailing space it may add to `output`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void extract(const char *input, char *output) {
  while (*input) {
    while (*input && !isdigit(*input)) ++input;
    while (isdigit(*input)) *output++ = *input++;
    *output++ = ' ';
  }
  *output = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
  char out[21];
  const char *in = "assdf4fdsdf65fsafda5";

  extract(in, out);
  printf("%s\n", out);
  return 0;
}
```

Output: `4 65 5`

Comment: Not integers though :) So you couldn't perform mathematical operations on them

Comment: @self Sounds like the OP wants a "string of number" as output. For what purpose, I don't know.

Comment: I agree. Very strange requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Yes using atoi you can extract integer no.

```
int atoi(const char *str)
```

Please refer following link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7842195/4112271

Comment: but atoi return integer type,do you known any way to convert to string type, I means char type

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this (not exhaustively tested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char non_num[] = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char str[]   = "assdf4fdsdf65fsafda5";
    char *next   = str;
    char *strptr = str;

    while( (next = strtok(strptr, non_num)) != NULL )
    {
        printf("%s ", next);
        strptr = NULL;
    }
    printf("\n");


    return(0);


}
```